# Charge separation equilibrium equation for non-rotating blackhole at Eddington limit with spherically symmetric accretion?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, charge, scattering, equilibrium

What is the formula for equilibrium charge on a non-rotating black hole with spherically symmetric hydrogen-1 inflow at the [Eddington limit of luminosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington_luminosity) based on photon scattering acceleration of electrons vs that of protons?

To the best of my knowledge no one has bothered to publish this.

It seems this would be an interesting boundary condition even though not expected to exist in reality. Perturbations involving rotation (or, say, various mixes of hydrogen isotopes) may lead to interesting generalizations.  Relativistic tangential velocities are more typical, so any net charge on the black hole might result in measurable magnetic effects.